# js not working when page not on same folder with masterpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Im using a responsive menu code which uses document.getElementById to trigger the menu.

It works for pages that are on the same folder as the masterpage. However for pages on a seperate folder, the menu isn't popping up.

Sample of the code:

```
<body>
    <div class="mp-pusher" id="mp-pusher">
        <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
        </nav>
    </div>
    <a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon-prev" href="#" id="trigger"><span>Menu</span></a>   

<script src="/CodeTest/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/CodeTest/js/mlpushmenu.js"></script>
<script>
    new mlPushMenu(document.getElementById('mp-menu'), document.getElementById('trigger'));
</script>
</body>
```

The script has to be in the body of the html for some reason as when I moved it up into the  it doesn't work.

Comment: you sure the js loading ?

Comment: open the console at your browser and copy the error to here please
to open it at chrome use `ctrl+shift+i`

Comment: 2 things, on your JavaScript files you are using relative paths, and if u put a script that's dependent on an element before the element load w/o waiting for an onload event its going to return null

Answer (score 0):

You need to show to the browser where to look for the JS file on the file you want to call the JS file.

If your JS file is in a folder called JS that is inside a folder called CodeTest, and you want to call this file in an html inside a folder called (for example) somethingFolder.. you should go back one level (. .) and then search for CodeTest -> js -> file.js, example:

```
src="../CodeTest/js/file.js"
```

Now if you want to call the JS file in a file that is on the same level of CodeTest folder, you must link without the dots (..), example:

```
src="CodeTest/js/file.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/classie.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/mlpushmenu.js'></script>
```